# Change Windows X and Y axis sensitivity separately?

Tags: autohotkey

I basically want to use a 4:3 resolution in Windows, but X axis sensitivity feels higher than Y's. How can I change them to be the same in a stretched resolution like 4:3? I need a simple way, maybe with AHK. I've looked for this script https://pastebin.com/gxS2gBi4 but I don't know what values to put in. Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by:

> I don't know what values to put in

Does the script even work for you?  It doesn't work for me even after it detects the wrong pointer size and relaunches as 32-bit.

That said, if it does work on your machine, you will have to use integers for acceleration (according to the documentation), so you would use two different integers for x and y to accelerate them at different rates, and then possibly use your mouse control panel to slow the mouse down overall so the whole thing isn't too fast.

For example, line 10 might look like this:

```
new MouseAccelerator(3, 4)
```

You can add a `MsgBox` to the `MouseAcceleratorEvent()` function to see if it's even getting called though, between lines 18 & 19.  Not getting called on my machine, so can't test any further

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks what I meant... However, the sensitivity will look to extreme when using 14:9 stretched resolutions. How can I slow it down? Maybe use 0.014 , 0.009? Can this work?